# Load Image using C#

Tags: c#, image, load

I
 open an Image i tried this methode but when i click on the button the window doesn't appear 
so i cant load an image

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = open.FileName;   

        }
```

Comment: What's happens if u debug this? Does your button click work?

Comment: no it doesn't @Sybren

Comment: There are 3 basic reasons why OpenFileDialog does not show a visible window.  It could be underneath another window, your Main() entrypoint is not declared properly and is missing [STAThread] or you have a buggy shell extension installed on the machine that deadlocks.  Your question does not help narrow down which of those three is the reason.

Comment: @HansPassant there is a button defined as button1. How do you know there is not any container window?! I think you are overthinking

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are "Open" and "Cancel" Buttons on OpenfileDialog. So because there is no "OK" button on it, "if condition" will not be true. You should change it to:

```
Private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (open.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
        {

            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = open.FileName;   

        }
    }
```

Comment: set a breakpoint in "if clause" and you will see it hits.
In your own code,  it wont be hit

Comment: Are you getting an exception? If yes, could you write exception message?

Comment: there's no exception , i tried to change some proprieties but no results

Answer (score 0):

Do this it will work perfectly and display full image.

```
 private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = open.FileName;
            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't work , the probleme is the window to select an image doesn't apear at all